# Debian 10.6 Tayga package missing in ISO default repository

Tags: linux, linux-networking, nat

I'd like to implement NAT64 on my Debian Linux server running on non-internet connection. But it seems that the Tayga package is not in the local repository.

apt install tayga -y

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package tayga

Has the tayga package been replaced other package name or no longer supported on Debian 10.6 version?
I can't find any document regarding to tayga package of debian 10.6 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently installed Tayga 0.9.2-8 in Debian Buster (also 10.6) and was OK!

The package Tayga 0.9.2-8 is included in `debian-10.6.0-amd64-DVD-12.iso`
You need to also have the above media file in order to be able to do an offline install of Tayga.

Does `apt search tayga` finds the package?

If not, check the listed mirrors in your /etc/apt/sources.list:

or you can manually download the package from [here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/tayga).

Comment: Did you use Debian default iso repository? my result of "apt search tayga" puts nothing.

Comment: Yes, but if you only have the first iso (the one you've booted with) you will not be able to install tayga package as it is stored in the: debian-10.6.0-amd64-DVD-12.iso. To check the media that a package is stored in, for debian, use this tool: https://cdimage-search.debian.org/

Comment: I think this comment about debian-10.6.0-amd64-DVD-12.iso  should  be included in the answer. Btw, 10.7.0 was released this week-end.

Comment: I dont have DVD2.iso so I just installed maually. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The tayga package is still in the Debian repos, just as it has been for over a decade. If you can't install it, something is wrong with your apt sources and you need to check those.

On a clean Debian buster system it will install with no problem.

```
root@vmtest-debian10:~# apt install tayga
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tayga
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 99.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 tayga amd64 0.9.2-8 [34.3 kB]
Fetched 34.3 kB in 0s (90.1 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package tayga.
(Reading database ... 37334 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tayga_0.9.2-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tayga (0.9.2-8) ...
Setting up tayga (0.9.2-8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u4) ...
```

Make sure you are using official Debian sources.

```
root@vmtest-debian10:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Comment: I was using "cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.~~~]" source not a http://deb.debian.org because I dont have access to connection. Maybe that's why my installtion is differ from other people.